# updating a pickle file from a dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

i am having a huge pickle file which needs to be updated in every 3 hrs from a dailydata file(a csv file.)

there are two field named TRX_DATE and TIME_STAMP in each two having values like 24/11/2015  and 24/11/2015 10:19:02 respectively.(also 50 additionl fields are there)

so what i am doing is first reading the huge pickle to a dataframe. Then dropping any values for today's date by comparing with TRX_DATE field.

Then reading that csv file to another dataframe. then appending both dataframe and again creating new pickle.

my scripts looks like

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pickle

df = pd.read_pickle('hugedata pickle')
Today = dt.datetime.today()
df = df[(df.TRX_DATE > Today)]  #delete any entries for today in main pickle

df1 = pd.read_csv(daily data csv file)

df = df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)

df.to_pickle('same huge data pickle')
```

problem is as follows

1.it is taking huge memory as well as time reading that huge pickle.

2.i need to append df1 to df and only columns from df should only remain and it should exclude if any new column from df1 getting appended. But i am getting new column values having NUN values at so many places.

So need assistance on these things

1.is there way that i will read the small sized csv only and append to pickle file ...(or reading that pickle is mandatory)

2.can it be done like converting the csv to pickle and merge two pickles. by load ,dump method (actually never used that)

3.how to read time  from TIME_STAMP field  and getting datas between two timestamp (filtering by TIME_STAMP).and upadting that to main pickle.previously i am filtering by TRX_DATE values.

Is there a better way--- please suggest.

Comment: Why do you use `read_pickle` and not `read_csv` ?

Comment: while i am reading from a pickle i am using read_pickle and while from csv i am using read_csv

Answer (score 3):

HDF5 is made for what you are trying to do.

```
import tables
import numpy as np
from pandas import HDFStore,DataFrame

df.to_hdf('test.h5',key='test1') # create an hdf5 file

pd.read_hdf('test.h5',key='test1') # read an hdf5 file
```

df.to_hdf() defaults to append mode.